# Newtonsoft.Json - Unexpected characters while parsing value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, dialogflow-es

I'm pulling intents back from API.AI and parsing these to C# objects using Newtonsoft.Json in the following way:-

```
intentListModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IntentListModel>>(intentList);
```

intentList is a JSON string from the webrequest. However at Line 1, position 161, it fails. The bit of JSON concerned is:-

```
"contextIn": [
    "Employed"
],
"events": [{
    "name": "Occupation_DOB"
}],
```

**NB: This is only part of the JSON, and the JSON opens and closes with [] as it is a list of JSON items.**

specifically the opening `{` on `events`. I'm stumped, I've run it through a validator and I see valid JSON.

Could anyone suggest what I can try, or is there a setting somewhere for this? Or is the error message actually looking another area of the JSON string?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Whole JSON sample posted

```
[
   {
      "id":"18b025c5-3567-49c1-a9e9-25583f9156ca",
      "name":"IncomeProtection -  Employed? - Occupation/DOB/Email",
      "state":"LOADED",
      "contextIn":[
         "Employed"
      ],
      "events":[
         {
            "name":"Occupation_DOB"
         }
      ],
      "parentId":"ad5f0007-c084-4615-93dd-6c82ca5e7602",
      "parameters":[
         {
            "required":true,
            "dataType":"@Occupation",
            "name":"Occupation",
            "value":"$Occupation",
            "prompts":[
               "Whatu0027s your Occupation?"
            ],
            "isList":false
         },
         {
            "required":true,
            "dataType":"@sys.date",
            "name":"date",
            "value":"$date",
            "prompts":[
               "Whatu0027s your date of birth?"
            ],
            "isList":false
         }
      ],
      "contextOut":[
         {
            "name":"OccupationDOB",
            "parameters":{

            },
            "lifespan":1
         }
      ],
      "actions":[
         "IncomeProtection:Occupation/DOB"
      ],
      "priority":500000,
      "fallbackIntent":false
   }
]
```

Comment: Please post a valid sample of the whole JSON and the classes which will also cause this issue

Comment: Done for you above.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the above more clear for you? 1 list item, with the suspected error in it.

Comment: The error says it occurs at position 161, which is the start of "contextIn": [
    "Employed"
]. What is the type of this in your class?

Comment: ContextIn is a list of string in my class.

Comment: What is the actual error text?

Comment: I've had two now. The original was "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].contextIn', line 1, position 161.'"

The next one is "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].contextIn', line 1, position 138.'"

Comment: I've created a DotNetFiddle using the JSON you provided and "it works": https://dotnetfiddle.net/6x3PmW

Comment: I suspect that this means there is an issue with a datatype in my class?

Comment: As Sir Rufo said: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here a .net fiddle with a class structure https://dotnetfiddle.net/L5pyqH - also working

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your input and your examples - all very much appreciated. In regards to this, the reason it failed was I missed interpreting the JSON. One of the parameters was a `List<string>` and my class was expecting a `string`.

Comment: Please answer your question so other don't have to go through the comments to find the answer you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was down to one of the items from the API being returned in a list, but in the particular example I looked at, the API returned a list of 1 item. I misread the brackets and created a class property of type `string` instead of `List<string>`, hence the failure of code.

Hope this helps people in the future.